# How to parse INI-like (or XML-like)files but with closing section tag?

Tags: java, fileparsing

I need to pase a text file in this format:

```
[section A begin]
some lines
more lines
[section 1 begin]
some lines
[section i begin]
some lines
[section i end]
more lines
[section 1 end]
more lines
[section A end]
[section B end]
...
[section B end]
```

Each section has 1 begin and 1 end tag; the sections may be nested but may not interleaving; the file may be large and cannot be read in memory as a whole.

Question: what is the easist way to parse such files(any open source libraries to use)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read one line at a time and parse it yourself.  It doesn't look very complex.

If the file is too large to read into memory, what do you intend to do with the data?